# Windows Phone app crashes when navigating back from a task

Tags: state, windows-phone-7, navigationcontroller

Some pages in my app allow users to click a hyperlink to launch the external browser via a WebBrowserHelper.

I'm carefully saving the app state in OnNavigatedFrom and restoring it in OnNavigatedTo, but when the user navigates back from the web browser into my app, the app hangs, then crashes.

I've carefully followed [the great blog post on the Windows Team Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/15/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-1.aspx), but can also reproduce the bug using the provided code there (just add a WebBrowserTask to one of the button click events on the DetailsPage; or in fact a send SMS task).

Can anyone else confirm this bug, or perhaps point out something special that needs to be done to overcome it?

Comment: did you try the debugger trick yochay mentions in his reply to your comment there?

Comment: Aha. Just saw that comment. My app is still crashing, but yes resuming the debugger fixes the demo code, so off I do debugging. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops! Yes it turns out in most cases you just need to resume the debugger to have the app come back to life.

However in my case there is also a bug in my own code. As usual.