# WebBrowserTask bug when pressing the back button very quickly (WP7)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a WebBrowserTask which is called when a button is clicked:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
        webBrowserTask.URL = "http://msdn.microsoft.com";
        webBrowserTask.Show();
    }
```

when i click this button in my app, and then I click the back button of the device very quickly, my app crashes, and the Application_Activated() method doesn't even called..

Is this a bug of the SDK? You can reproduce the problem very easily on the emulator or on your device.

Any workarounds? This seems to happen in all tasks (sms, email etc).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's your Application_Activated being skipped and not your Constructor?

If it's crashing because your constructors not being called it's likely you've restarted your app fast enough for it to have not been tombstoned as Peter describes in more detail here.

[How to correctly handle application deactivation and reactivation - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/12/11/how-to-correctly-handle-application-deactivation-and-reactivation.aspx)

If this isn't the case either, is it possible your app wasn't initially created using the RTM tools and needs to be migrated per the new project templates?

Comment: the strange thing is that after it exits, if I press Run in Visual Studio, it continues from where it had left off, by calling the activate method!

Comment: if I try to resume it from the device, nothing happens, it stops at the loading screen and stays there for ever.

Comment: i can certainly have a look at reproducing it, can I ask first though, have you reproduced this behaviour in a blank project? if any small bits of code are required to repro it, could you show us those in your original question as an edit? (ps best to chat in comments rather than make new answers)

Comment: yes you can reproduce it with a blank project, just create a new project with a button that starts a new WebBrowserTask. Then click the button and after 1 sec press the back button. Do it several times. If it doesn't happen with the first try, re-deploy and try it again. It just exits with no exception and the activated method is never called, or any other method.

Comment: i found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260968/windows-phone-app-crashes-when-navigating-back-from-a-task , it seems that when the phone is connected and you run the app through the debugger, when you come back from a task you have to press F5 again to resume the debugger... if you run the app on the phone, without the debugger everything is normal. thanks for your help MickN

Comment: No worries, glad you're sorted. You should be seeing a black screen when you get this. Rather than crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to another page/task is not a synchronous process where you call the page and wait for a return result. If you are fast enough, you close your application the normal way before the task even startet.

Comment: if this was the case then it should execute the Application_Closing() method but it doesn't. Or if there was an bug in the Application_Deactivated() method, I should get an exception or something. The Application_Deactivated() method executes normally.