# WP7: Launch WebBrowserTask and return to app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I need to launch a WebBrowserTask (to a YouTubePage) from a HyperLinkButton in my WP7 application.
This is the (simple) code:

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
        browser.Uri = (sender as HyperlinkButton).NavigateUri;
        browser.Show();
    }
```

The problem is that when i want to go back to the app page using the Back Button, the app crash or says "I'm resuming" but doesn't go back to the previous page. 
I've tried to handle ApplicationActivated or ApplicationDeactivated but with no success.

I've also notice that other apps does "create" a new istance in the Fast App Switcher, while my app is "overwritten" by the BrowserTask in the App Switcher.

Any advice will be helpful. Thanks ad sorry for my english..

Comment: Same question as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594457/webbrowsertask-bug-when-pressing-the-back-button-very-quickly-wp7?rq=1

Comment: Yes, but does not solve the issue for me. Even if i continue the debug or I launch the app from a device in execute mode only..

Comment: Have you tried logging exceptions in two main App exception handlers and examining them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, thanks all. In the HyperLinkButton i had already set the value NavigateUri=""myurl", and with the code in my first post i declare a second WebBrowserTask, so there were essentially two browser opened at the same time. Removing this code:

```
WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
browser.Uri = (sender as HyperlinkButton).NavigateUri;
browser.Show();
```

it all works fine, beside that i have to press the Back Button twice to return to my app..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
            task.Uri = new Uri("your uri", UriKind.Absolute);
            task.Show();
```